# Backbone: практика создания виджетов

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Допустим хочу написать виджет для показа сообщения, но не хочу работать непосредственно с модель, а через интерфейс. Вот что примерно пришло в голову:

```
var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ /*some code*/ });
var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({ /*some code*/ });

var msg = new function(){
    this.model = new MessageModel();
    this.view = new MessageView({model:this.model});    
}
msg.show = function(text){
    this.model.set('message', text);
}
msg.clear = function(){
    this.model.set('message', '');
}
msg.show('Some');
```

На сколько это правильно, есть ли другие практики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем это, собственно, отличается от манипулирования моделью? Если вы расширите объект MessageModel (через `extend()`) и добавите в него методы `show(msg)` и `clear()`, то будет то же самое. Смысл создавать дополнительный объект и смысл в него инкапсулировать View?